# How do I post a message to a Azure Service Bus from my Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am playing around with Azure functions and trying to setup an intricate construct of pipes and filters (the pattern). I am using Azure functions for this.

My starting point is a HTTP triggered Azure function. That collects some JSON from the body of the request and should pass this message to a Azure Service Bus.

I must be missing something here (I have done this before in RabbitMQ with console apps) but how do I post a message to a service bus from a HTTP triggered Azure function.

I found several references talking about configuring my function.json (what ever that is - im building in Visual Studio).

How does this input/output (trigger/binding) thing work - im guessing that is the problem here...or??

I have my first Azure function in place and is receiving the data from the HTTP - so far so good. But how to proceed?

** Update **
Still cant get it to Work. Got this code and it fails with an http500. (it also says i need to see the og - where is that log?)

```
public static class EI_WooCommerce_Hub
    {
        [FunctionName("EI_WooCommerce_Hub")]
        [return: ServiceBus("eilogging", Connection = "EIIntegrationServiceBusConnection")]
        public async static Task<string> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "EIWooCommerceHub/name/")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Webhook triggered from: ");            
            return "Hello World to queue";
        }       
    }
```

** Update 2 **
This seems to be a config problem. In the application settings on the function app I kept getting an authorization error for the servicebus. I added the default "AzureWebJobsServiceBus" setting with the connectionstring, then it worked. It could not pick up my own connection string for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Service Bus output binding. Since you mentioned Visual Studio, I assume C#. The simplest ever example looks like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input)
{
    return input.Text;
}
```

Then add an application setting called `ServiceBusConnection` with the connection string to a namespace with queue `myqueue` (or rename in attribute constructor).

You can find more in [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions - Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that was the missing part, cheers. One other thing - how about that "application setting" where do I specify that one for my function?

Comment: @BrianHvarregaard Locally in `local.settings.json`, in Azure in Application Setting portal screen

Comment: thanks a lot, its starting to make more sense. I still cant get it to work. I get http 500 errors. I have updated the code above (the original post) to include my source code that fails. (btw - where do I see the log it mentions in the error)

Comment: This approach has the HttpTrigger responding with a 200 with no body. Is there a way to configure the response to the HttpTrigger using the service bus output binding?

Comment: Yes, sure, you can use an `out` parameter for the service bus binding, similar to the other answer here.

Comment: How do I add a message to the queue using this code? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#usage) I read that the `Add` method should be used.

Answer (score 0):

When you build in Visual Studio, then the `function.json` is created automatically. All you have to do is to define your triggers and output as attributes of the function parameters (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output)

A minimalistic example:

```cs
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [ServiceBus("myqueue")] out string sbMessage,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    sbMessage = name;
}
```

Comment: This code will not compile, since `async` methods do not support `out` parameters.